# Should offline algorithms (SAC, DDGP, TD3) be used with suprocesses vectorized environements?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I read most of offline algorithms from Stable Baselines 3 should not be subprocessed (see here : https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rl_tips.html - "Which algorithm should I use?" section).

I currently use SAC with a SubprocVecEnv wrapper and it seems work except episode based "train_freq" (ex : (10, 'episode')) cannot be used...

Is usage of multiprocess have a kind of "conceptual incompatibility" with offline algorithm or is it a problem of SB' documentation updating ?